# Background Image smaller than Screen: Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm currently using SpriteKit, I'm using a SKSpriteNode as the background, however, with the code I'm using the image comes out to be slightly smaller than the screen.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SKSpriteNode *backgroundImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"testBackground"];
backgroundImage.size = self.view.frame.size;
backgroundImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.scene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.scene.frame));
[self addChild:backgroundImage];
```

And this is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

Note: My image is the exact size of the screen, so I'm not sure how this 'border' is around it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

In my .SKS file I changed the width to 1080 and the height to 1920. Doing that and changing the line:

```
backgroundImage.size = self.view.frame.size;
```

to:

```
backgroundImage.size = self.size;
```

as KnightOfDragon recommended seemed to fix the problem.

A good thing to note is that if the aspect ratio to your image is 16:9, then it won't fill the screen on devices such as the 4S or iPad.

Comment: This causes a lot of other issues, and I think you mean `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit`

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines:

```
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[backgroundImage setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[self addChild:backgroundImage];
```

Comment: All this would do is put the background image center at the lower right corner of the screen, and hide any black bars

Answer (score 1):

See this line : `backgroundImage.size = self.view.frame.size;`  This is bad, your `SKNode`s should not know anything about the view.  Instead, you need to do `scene.size` (If you are in the Game Scene file, then `self.size`),  this way, no matter what `scaleMode` you decide to choose, the background image size will relate to the scene size,  then the scene will decide how to present in the view.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and see if changing back to the original scale value fixes the problem

Comment: Changing to resize fill means that if you go to different devices,  the game area size is different,  so if you design on an iPhone 4s, on an iPad, everything will be tiny

Comment: I did this, the image is the right width but the height is messed up, it is like 3 times smaller than what it should be and it's making the image look squashed.

Comment: that means your scene is 3 times larger than the view

Comment: What is the expected scale mode

Comment: SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit

Comment: what is the default aspect ratio (3:4 ,2:3,9:16)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121204/discussion-between-nickolaus-and-knight0fdragon).